# Why is my Swing program still advancing?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, ioexception, dice

So I have my program using JButtons with actionListeners attached, but when the program hits a certain point where it should wait for an action to be performed, it skips right over the waiting, and just continues on. I am wondering if it is due to there being no IOException being thrown, but if I throw it, it just returns a bunch of errors, which creates a huge mess.

And yes, I know that I am mixing command line with swing. That is because it started out as command line, and now I am making it swing.

Can anyone point out an easier way to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
public static void choiceRerollDice() {
            if (!canRerollDiceOne && !canRerollDiceTwo && !canRerollDiceThree && !canRerollDiceFour && !canRerollDiceFive) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, but you may not reroll any more dice...");
            displayDiceValues();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else {
    System.out.println("Would you like to reroll any (more) dice? (yes/no)");
            area = "choiceReroll";
            }
}

public static void rerollChoice(String choiceReroll) {
    switch (choiceReroll) {
                case "yes":
                    rerollDice();
                    break;
                case "no":
                    //endTurn();
                    displayDiceValues();
                    f.validate();
                    f.repaint();
                    //calculatePlayer1Score();
                    //System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                    //System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    invalidInput();
    }
}

public static void rerollDice() {
    Scanner is = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Which dice would you like to reroll? (Click the box under the dice!)");        
    rollSel = is.next();
    switch (rollSel) {
        case "roll":
        if (willRerollDiceOne) {
            if (canRerollDiceOne) {
                diceOne = 0;
                rollDiceOne();
                canRerollDiceOne = false;
                box1.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("error");
            }
        }

        else {
        }
        if (willRerollDiceTwo) {
            if (canRerollDiceTwo) {
            diceTwo = 0;
            rollDiceTwo();
            canRerollDiceTwo = false;
            box2.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("error");
            }
        }
        else {
        }
        if (willRerollDiceThree) {
            if (canRerollDiceThree) {
            diceThree = 0;
            rollDiceThree();
            canRerollDiceThree = false;
            box3.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        else {
        }
        if (willRerollDiceFour) {
            if (canRerollDiceFour) {
            diceFour = 0;
            rollDiceFour();
            canRerollDiceFour = false;
            box4.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        else {
        }
        if (willRerollDiceFive) {
            if (canRerollDiceFive) {
            diceFive = 0;
            rollDiceFive();
            canRerollDiceFive = false;
            box5.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        else {
        }
        box1.setSelected(false);
        box2.setSelected(false);
        box3.setSelected(false);
        box4.setSelected(false);
        box5.setSelected(false);
        f.validate();
        f.repaint();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error...");
            break;
    }
    choiceRerollDice();
}
```

Here are the JButtons:

```
public static JButton textYes = new JButton("Yes");
public static JButton textNo = new JButton("No");
```

And for the actionListeners:

```
      textYes.addActionListener(this);
      textNo.addActionListener(this);
```

And the actionPerformed():

```
        if ("choiceReroll".equals(area)) {
            if(e.getSource() == textYes){
                rerollChoice("yes");
            }
            if(e.getSource() == textNo){
                rerollChoice("no");
            }
        }
```

But instead of stopping to wait for input at:

```
        else {
    System.out.println("Would you like to reroll any (more) dice? (yes/no)");
            area = "choiceReroll";
            }
```

It just continues on to `rerollDice()`

Any ideas?

Comment: You're mixing a Swing GUI application with a console application. The solution is to just don't do this. Stick with just a Swing GUI application and get all input through the GUI. You appear to be over-using statics as well. Most all of your critical fields and methods should be non-static instance methods.

Comment: If you read the beginning of my question, you would see why I did this.

Comment: `"And yes, I know that I am mixing command line with swing. That is because it started out as command line, and now I am making it swing."` is not a valid reason for this. If you are making a Swing application, make a Swing application. It appears that you've already been told this by MadProgrammer in your last question. He knows his Swing, and I suggest that you heed his advice.

Comment: And with the static methods, if one of them isn't static, it keeps telling me that non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: Then you're fixing the wrong thing. The solution is not to make all static but to not make non-static calls in a static way.

Comment: Not to mention that, even if mixing was not a bad idea, `System.out.println` just prints a message and will not expect user entry, so the line does not wait at all.

Comment: I am making it all swing, but I have to actually make the changes. So for a little while, there will still be some command line attributes, but I am converting them all to swing.

Comment: Then I would delete this question and come back if still having problems after you've switched it all to Swing. Again as had been said before and as we're saying now, you shouldn't mix the two.

Comment: @SJuan76 I know that, but if you notice, the method ends right there...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The thing is, I'm still in the process of teaching myself Java, and I could use a little bit of help. Also, I have been taking peoples advice and help.

Comment: @user2506658: but you've been given advice -- don't mix the two. Until you follow this, your program will not work. How can we convince you of this? That and get rid of most of your statics.

Comment: How am I supposed to learn if I don't ask for help? I'm not asking about the command line part, I'm asking why it begins at another method. And I'm not "mixing" them, I'm switching from one to the other.

Comment: I'm betting that it will be difficult to say why you're having your problem as we cannot compile and run your code, and so we cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: I can post it on PasteBin, if that helps?

Comment: Normally I'd say no, but I'm guessing that you're not going to be able to make and post here an [sscce](http://sscce.org) just yet, but that would be the better option.

Comment: That was an SSCCE, in my opinion. But anyways, here is my complete [code](http://pastebin.com/jNszJW1C)

Comment: Can I copy and paste your code above and run it? Will it reproduce your error? is it very short and does nothing but reproduce the error? None of these conditions are fulfilled, so I don't know how you can say it even approaches an SSCCE. You will want to re-look at the [sscce](http://sscce.org) specification.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now... Sorry, I had interpreted SSCCE as just the code that is causing the problem... My bad.

Comment: What misbehaviors is your code experiencing?

Comment: So, when I hit 'Yes', it prints: Rolling..., lists the dice values, then it says: Would you like to reroll any (more) dice? (yes/no). But then it also asks, "Which dice would you like to reroll? (Click the box under the dice!)" The last question shouldn't be asked until after 'Yes' is clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General Suggestions:

- Since you've gotten rid of most use of the Scanner (good for you!) and the blocking `while (true)` loops, at present you don't need to use background threads. I would get rid of it and only use it if needed.
- Your class is huge and unwieldy making it very hard for us (and likely for you!) to follow the logic contained. This is one reason for refactoring code, for splitting it up into constituent classes, each with its own responsibility.
- By doing this, you will be forced to use non-static fields and methods and to eliminate most of your use of static -- a ***very*** good thing.
- Likewise use of arrays and Lists such as ArrayLists will help you eliminate redundant code making debugging and modifying much easier.

Specific Suggestions:

- Your program logic is only doing what you tell it to do. Put more println statements in your code to see what I mean. If you do this:

inside of actionPerformed:

```
        if ("choiceReroll".equals(area)) {
           System.out.println("choiceReroll equals area");
           if (e.getSource() == textYes) {
              System.out.println("source is textYes");
              rerollChoice("yes");
           }
           if (e.getSource() == textNo) {
              rerollChoice("no");
           }
        }
```

You'll see that rerollChoice("yes") is called when the textYes button is pressed.

Continue sprinkling your code with println's to see what I mean. More specific recs may be forthcoming. Or better -- learn to use and then use a debugger.

---

**Edit**

For example, here is a slightly overly long sample program that shows some of what I mean. Note that it is composed of several classes and enums, the latter to hold "state" values of objects.

OK, but seriously, so far this is the best damn dice game program that I've yet written. Ha!

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

/**
 * DiceGame.java
 * previously called Greed2.java
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264671/why-is-my-swing-program-still-advancing
 * @author Pete
 * 6/24/2013
 */
public class DiceGame {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      DicePanel mainPanel = new DicePanel();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dice Game");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DicePanel extends JPanel {
   private static final String FIRST_ROLL_STATUS_TEXT = "Please select die to re-roll and press Second Roll";
   private static final String RESET_STATUS_TEXT = "Please press the First Roll Button";
   private static final String SECOND_ROLL_STATUS_TEXT = "Please press the Reset Button";
   private Die[] dieArray = new Die[5];
   private GameState gameState = GameState.FIRST_ROLL;
   private JButton rollButton = new JButton();
   private JButton exitButton = new JButton();
   private JTextArea messageArea = new JTextArea(20, 60);
   private Map<GameState, Action> rollActionMap = new HashMap<>();
   private JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel("  ");

   public DicePanel() {
      rollActionMap.put(GameState.FIRST_ROLL, new RollAction(this, GameState.FIRST_ROLL));
      rollActionMap.put(GameState.SECOND_ROLL, new RollAction(this, GameState.SECOND_ROLL));
      rollActionMap.put(GameState.RESET, new RollAction(this, GameState.RESET));

      exitButton.setAction(new ExitAction());

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      int gap = 3;
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap));
      add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(new JScrollPane(messageArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(createSouthPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      setGameState(GameState.RESET);
      setGameState(GameState.FIRST_ROLL);
   }

   private JPanel createSouthPanel() {
      int gap = 20;
      JPanel diePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, gap, gap));
      for (int i = 0; i < dieArray.length; i++) {
         dieArray[i] = new Die();
         diePanel.add(dieArray[i].getDieLabel());
      }

      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 10, 10));
      buttonPanel.add(rollButton);
      buttonPanel.add(exitButton);
      JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      southPanel.add(diePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      southPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      return southPanel;
   }

   public GameState getGameState() {
      return gameState;
   }

   public void rollAll() {
      for (Die die : dieArray) {
         die.roll();
         die.setSelectable(true);
      }
   }

   public void rollSelected() {
      for (Die die : dieArray) {
         if (die.isSelected()) {
            die.roll();
         }
         die.setSelected(false);
         die.setSelectable(false);
      }
   }

   public void setGameState(GameState gameState) {
      GameState currentState = this.gameState;
      this.gameState = gameState;
      rollButton.setAction(rollActionMap.get(gameState));

      if (currentState == GameState.RESET) {
         reset();
      } else if (currentState == GameState.FIRST_ROLL) {
         firstRoll();
      } else if (currentState == GameState.SECOND_ROLL) {
         secondRoll();
      }
   }

   private void firstRoll() {
      rollAll();
      statusLabel.setText(FIRST_ROLL_STATUS_TEXT);
   }

   private void secondRoll() {
      rollSelected();

      // TODO: calculate score and display

      statusLabel.setText(SECOND_ROLL_STATUS_TEXT);
   }

   public void reset() {
      for (Die die : dieArray) {
         die.reset();
      }
      statusLabel.setText(RESET_STATUS_TEXT);
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class RollAction extends AbstractAction {
   private DicePanel dicePanel;

   public RollAction(DicePanel dicePanel, GameState gameState) {
      super(gameState.getText());
      this.dicePanel = dicePanel;
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, gameState.getMnemonic());
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      dicePanel.setGameState(dicePanel.getGameState().next());
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ExitAction extends AbstractAction {
   private static final String EXIT = "Exit";

   public ExitAction() {
      super(EXIT);
      putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_X);
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(((Component)e.getSource()));
      win.dispose();
   }
}

enum GameState {
   FIRST_ROLL("First Roll", KeyEvent.VK_F), SECOND_ROLL("Second Roll", KeyEvent.VK_S), 
   RESET("Reset", KeyEvent.VK_R);

   private String text;
   private int mnemonic;

   private GameState(String text, int mnemonic) {
      this.text = text;
      this.mnemonic = mnemonic;
   }

   public int getMnemonic() {
      return mnemonic;
   }

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }

   public GameState next() {
      int ordinal = ordinal();
      ordinal++;
      ordinal %= values().length;
      return values()[ordinal];
   }
}

class Die {
   private static final int BORDER_GAP = 3;
   private static final Border SELECTED_BORDER = 
         BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, BORDER_GAP);
   private static final Border UNSELECTED_BORDER = 
         BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(BORDER_GAP, BORDER_GAP, BORDER_GAP, BORDER_GAP);

   private JLabel dieLabel = new JLabel();
   private Random random = new Random();
   private DieValue dieValue = DieValue.BLANK;
   private boolean selectable = false;
   private boolean selected = false;

   public Die() {
      reset();
      dieLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
            if (selectable) {
               setSelected(!selected);
            }
         }
      });
   }

   public Component getDieLabel() {
      return dieLabel;
   }

   public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
      this.selected = selected;
      Border border = selected ? SELECTED_BORDER : UNSELECTED_BORDER;
      dieLabel.setBorder(border);
   }

   public void roll() {
      int value = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
      dieValue = DieValue.getDieValue(value);
      dieLabel.setIcon(dieValue.getIcon());
   }

   public void reset() {
      dieValue = DieValue.BLANK;
      setSelected(false);
      setSelectable(false);
      dieLabel.setIcon(dieValue.getIcon());
   }

   public DieValue getValue() {
      return dieValue;
   }

   public boolean isSelected() {
      return selected;
   }

   public boolean isSelectable() {
      return selectable;
   }

   public void setSelectable(boolean selectable) {
      this.selectable = selectable;
   }
}

enum DieValue {
   BLANK(0, ""), 
   ONE(1, "One"), TWO(2, "Two"), THREE(3, "Three"), 
   FOUR(4, "Four"), FIVE(5, "Five"), SIX(6, "Six");

   private static final int OUT_FRAME = 110;
   private static final int ARC = 16;
   private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 4f;
   private static final int SML_GAP = 2;
   private static final int OVAL_RADIUS = 24;
   private Icon icon;
   private String name;
   private int value;

   private DieValue(int value, String name) {
      this.value = value;
      this.name = name;
      this.icon = createIcon(value);
   }

   private Icon createIcon(int value) {
      BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(OUT_FRAME, OUT_FRAME, 
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
      Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(STROKE_WIDTH);
      g2.setColor(Color.white);
      g2.fillRoundRect(0, 0, OUT_FRAME, OUT_FRAME, ARC, ARC);
      g2.setColor(Color.black);
      g2.setStroke(stroke);
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.drawRoundRect(SML_GAP, SML_GAP, OUT_FRAME - SML_GAP * 2, 
            OUT_FRAME - SML_GAP * 2, ARC, ARC);


      g2.setColor(Color.black);
      switch (value) {
      case 1:
         fillOval(g2, 1, 1);
         break;
      case 2:
         fillOval(g2, 0, 0);
         fillOval(g2, 2, 2);
         break;
      case 3:
         fillOval(g2, 0, 0);
         fillOval(g2, 1, 1);
         fillOval(g2, 2, 2);
         break;
      case 4:
         fillOval(g2, 0, 0);
         fillOval(g2, 0, 2);
         fillOval(g2, 2, 0);
         fillOval(g2, 2, 2);
         break;
      case 5:
         fillOval(g2, 0, 0);
         fillOval(g2, 0, 2);
         fillOval(g2, 1, 1);
         fillOval(g2, 2, 0);
         fillOval(g2, 2, 2);
         break;
      case 6:
         fillOval(g2, 0, 0);
         fillOval(g2, 0, 1);
         fillOval(g2, 0, 2);
         fillOval(g2, 2, 0);
         fillOval(g2, 2, 1);
         fillOval(g2, 2, 2);
         break;

      default:
         break;
      }

      g2.dispose();
      return new ImageIcon(img);
   }

   private void fillOval(Graphics2D g2, int row, int col) {
      double rectWidth = OUT_FRAME - 4 * STROKE_WIDTH;
      int x = (int) (2 * STROKE_WIDTH - OVAL_RADIUS / 2 + (col + 0.5) * rectWidth / 3);
      int y = (int) (2 * STROKE_WIDTH - OVAL_RADIUS / 2 + (row + 0.5) * rectWidth / 3);

      g2.fillOval(x, y, OVAL_RADIUS, OVAL_RADIUS);
   }

   public static DieValue getDieValue(int value) {
      for (DieValue dieImage : DieValue.values()) {
         if (dieImage.getValue() == value) {
            return dieImage;
         }
      }
      return null;
   }

   public Icon getIcon() {
      return icon;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public int getValue() {
      return value;
   }

}
```

This displays as:

First Roll:
[image: First Roll]

Second Roll:
[image: Second Roll]

Reset:
[image: Reset]

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. And I still cannot figure out why people always downvote my questions when I follow all the rules and all the advice given. So I may not use this site for a while... Thanks for your help... I guess.

Comment: @user2506658: your questions are difficult to answer because they are incomplete and require a lot of pulling information out of you. You will get more positive votes and better answers if you ask answerable questions from the get-go. Please have a look at [Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) for more on how to write better questions. The blog has helped me immensely and can help you to.